# iOS stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString - UI freeze

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, stringbyevaluatingjavascr

In my iOS app (a kind of flashCard application) I'm using a `UIWebView` and once the `webview` content loading is finished I need to perform some UI operations (changes).
I'm checking for this in `webViewDidFinishLoad`.
When a user taps on a card it will flip and different content is gets loaded. I am using the code below in this `flipAction` as well as in `swipeAction` (when user moves from one card to another) to check:

```
if (![[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.readyState"] isEqualToString:@"complete"])
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(myCustomMethod:) withObject:self afterDelay:3.0];
}
```

Sometimes, not always, my UI will freeze on the above if condition and after that the UI will not respond further. The app must be manually killed and relaunched.

Do I need to call `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`: method other than thread?
or what may be the cause for this?

Comment: Are you performing some UI updates in the if block? Does the code you posted run on the main thread?

Comment: Ya I'm performing UI Updates using main thread only.

Answer (score 1):

You can try background thread

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        // async operation
        // Call your method here

                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // Update UI here

                });
    });
```